# Resolving TFS WorkItem Assigned-To and Created-By to email address

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I'm working with some custom reporting in TFS. I have a set of `WorkItem` instances that I want to get the information about the Creator and Assigned-To from.

```
WorkItem wi = GetWorkItem( ... );
String assignedTo = (String)wi.Fields[CoreField.AssignedTo].Value;
String createdBy  = (String)wi.Fields[CoreField.CreatedBy].Value;
```

The problem is that the fields are raw string values that contain the display-name of the user. I have to store my own database that maps these display-names to their Active Directory identities (by their username or email address).

Obviously maintaining my own parallel database of users isn't the right way - is there any other way to get from `wi.Fields[CoreField.AssignedTo].Value` to a security identity object, or at least the user's username or email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `IIdentityManagementService2` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.iidentitymanagementservice2.aspx) in order to get details about the identity using the display name. You can get the service in the same fashion as you would get the `WorkItemStore` from the project collection object using `TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService<IIdentityManagementService2>()`. If you cast the `AssignedTo` value into a string, you can use the following code to get the identity:

```
var identity = identityService.ReadIdentity(
            IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName, 
            assignedTo, 
            MembershipQuery.Direct,
            ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);
```

Where `assignedTo` would be the value of the display name that you retrieve from the field in the work item.

Comment: Is there a way to get actual Usernames using some approach? The above solution works for us in most cases, but there are instances where same display name is used by Multiple Users, under this scenario, we get **"com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.webservices.IdentityManagementException: Multiple identities were found that matched the factor value ‘<display name>’"** Error.

Comment: You could probably use the `ReadIdentities()` method and throw the display name in an array (or something, i'm not sure what the method parameters are off the top of my head) to return multiple identities that match the criteria.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a while but I've stumbled into your answer while troubleshooting an issue related to this exact code. After we migrated to ADO from on-prem we had to authenticate to the TFSProjectCollection using PAT. We're able to authenticate to TFSProjectCollection with it, but still end up with an UnauthorizedException when we're trying to get the email via the IdentityManagementService.  Curious if you'd know whether it's just an additional permission I need to grant via PAT, or are there a couple more steps needed for this code to work in ADO?

Comment: @robertviper08 -- sorry i dont work on TFS/Azure Devops any longer. From what I remember that service needed server-level permissions which I don't think you can get using the hosted service. You may want to switch to using the REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1